# Display fullscreen image, wait2 seconds, close image, open div - javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I 'm trying to open fullscreen image for 2 seconds and then close the image. After the image is closed, another element is shown.

```
$("#explosion-image").attr('src', %image_url%);
$("#explosion-image").css({
   height:'100%', width:'100%', position:'fixed', top:0, left:0
});
$("#explosion-image").show();
$("#explosion-image").delay(2000);
$("#explosion-image").hide();
$("#explosion-image").attr('src', '');
$("#div-to-open").show();
```

This code only opens the image and than does nothing :(

Thanks for help in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this fiddle out:

http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/JhcGb/

```
$("#explosion-image").css({
    height: '100%',
    width: '100%',
    position: 'fixed',
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    display: 'none'
}).show()
setTimeout(function() {
    $("#div-to-open").show();
    $("#explosion-image").hide();
}, 2000)
```

Answer (score 1):

`delay()` only really works on animations. You should use `setTimeout` instead. Even if it works, you need to chain the calls:

```
$("#explosion-image").show().delay(2000).hide();
```